# How can I make a console-like textbox?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, simulation

I am making a program called "BasicSys". It is a BASIC System simulator that uses a textbox for the console. So far I have everything working great but I need to have the text box act like a command prompt window. It needs to be able to ask for input and retreive the value without allowing the user to modify anything outside of the prompt space (the space where the user should only be able to type is after a ":" or a ">"). Some feilds are password feilds that require either no echoing or having the chartacters replaced by *'s. Is it possible to make a console out of a textbox?

P.S. I also want to know if there are any small BASIC v2 compilers for Win32 so BasicSys can compile and run BASIC programs.

Comment: Basically I want to treat a text box as if it were a command prompt console or something.

Comment: Can you make it read-only and handle keyboard events manually? That means inserting characters on key pressed, handling clipboard and other shortcuts.

Comment: Or just use a multiline textbox for output, and a single line textbox underneath for input.  No need for any ":" or ">", when the user can type the cursor (caret) would be visible there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how realistic you want it to be you can use the API to open a real console window and interact with it. There are many examples available that you can find by searching such as [this one](http://internettrash.com/users/fdb/cons.htm). My suggestion though would be to fake it with a multi-line textbox. It would not be very tricky. Set an index every time you draw the prompt, then as long as the cursor is positioned after the index the textbox is read / write. If the user scrolls backwards make the textbox read only. It should be fairly simple using the KeyDown event and setting the ReadOnly property True / False to get a passable "command" window.